# Mips program to Count No of occurrences for each character in paragraph

Tags: mips

How can I write a Program in Mips to Count No of occurrences for each character in paragraph?
I wrote the program in c language but Couldn't convert it to Mips.
this is the c code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
   char para[100];

   printf("Enter Paragraph : ");
   scanf("%[^\n]s", para);

   int length = strlen(para),i,j;
    int freq[length]; //array of frequncy char
   for(i = 0; i < strlen(para); i++) {
        freq[i] = 1;
        for(j = i+1; j < strlen(para); j++) {
            if(para[i] == para[j]) {
                freq[i]++;

                para[j] = '0'; ////Set para[j] to 0 to avoid printing visited character
            }
        }
    }
     printf("Characters and their corresponding frequencies\n");
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(para[i] != ' ' && para[i] != '0')
            printf("%c-%d\n", para[i], freq[i]);
    }




   return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/ check here what would be generated from the C code to get some ideas

Comment: Show your C code and let us know where you're stuck.  Each construct in C has a translation in assembly: functions, input/output, if statements, while/for loops.

Comment: Ok, so the good news is that you don't need to do any function calling or implementation, just a main.  Suggest that since this is a `main` program, to use global data for `para` and `freq`.  Also, it would help to know if this is for MARS/QtSPIM or other environment.  If MARS/QtSPIM we do the `scanf` via syscalls, and `printf` same.

Comment: ok, but what about the nested loop ?

Comment: I made a simple code but there were an error in the output

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the paragraph but i have a one for a string;

```
.data 
string:      .space 100                    
.text
main: 
    la $a0, string                             # input string
    li $a1, 100                                # maximum size of string
    li $v0, 8                                  # represents reading string
    syscall                                    # call system

    li $v0, 12                                 # 12 represents reading character
    syscall                                    # call system  
    move $s2, $v0                              # $s2= character
    li $s1, 100                                # $s1= maximum size of string
           
    li  $t4, 0                                 # count (number of occurrances)
    li  $t0, 0                                 # i(index)

    bge $t0, $s1, print                        # i>= string length, exit    

loop:                        

    lb  $s0,($a0)                              # the first character of string into $s0 
    bne $s0, $s2, skip                         # skip increasing the counter if item does not equal               
    add $t4, $t4, 1                            # otherwise increment the counter    
skip: 
    addiu $a0, $a0, 1                            # increment index
    beq $s0,0,print                             # go to print label if $s0=0 so $s0 ='\0' 
    j  loop                                    # go back to loop

print:                                     # print the result

   #addi $v0, $t4, 0                           # $v0= $v4= number of occurrences
   li $v0,1                                   # 1 represents printing integer                   
   move $a0,$t4                               # $a0=$t4 = number of occurances of character
   syscall                                    # call system    

 # Terminate the program
   li $v0, 10                                 # 10 represents exit
   syscall                                    # call system
```

The input/output isn't structured well in this, just write the sentence at first then enter and write the character you want to get the occurrence of.
Hope this could in any way help you